# JPA only returns first instance of @ManyToOne object

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

## Problem

I have two objects, `Deck` and `Card`, that have a many-to-many relationship. The entity for the join table is `DeckCard`, containing an embedded id `DeckCardId` to facilitate accessing cards from inside deck objects without creating an infinite loop. (All the code is below.)

When I retrieve all decks using `JpaRepository.findAll()`, I correctly receive a list of all decks, each of which has a `cards` attribute containing a list of DeckCards. When drilling down into `DeckCard.id.card`, I expect to see the full `Card` object with all its attributes, like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Deck 1",
        "cards":[
            {
                "id":{
                    "deck":1,
                    "card":{
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"Card 1"
                    }
                },
                ...
            },
            {
                "id":{
                    "deck":1,
                    "card":{
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"Card 2"
                    }
                },
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Deck 2",
        "cards":[
            {
                "id":{
                    "deck":2,
                    "card":{
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"Card 1"
                    }
                },
                ...
            },
            {
                "id":{
                    "deck":2,
                    "card":{
                        "id":3,
                        "name":"Card 3"
                    }
                },
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Deck 3",
        "cards":[
            {
                "id":{
                    "deck":3,
                    "card":{
                        "id":3,
                        "name":"Card 3"
                    }
                },
                ...
            },
            {
                "id":{
                    "deck":3,
                    "card":{
                        "id":4,
                        "name":"Card 4"
                    }
                },
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

For the first appearance of each `Card`, this is true; however, for all subsequent appearances of that card in other decks, all I get is the id of the card:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Deck 1",
        "cards":[
            {
                "id":{
                    "deck":1,
                    "card":{
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"Card 1"
                    }
                },
                ...
            },
            {
                "id":{
                    "deck":1,
                    "card":{
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"Card 2"
                    }
                },
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Deck 2",
        "cards":[
            {
                "id":{
                    "deck":2,
                    "card":1 // I expected this to be the full model of Card 1
                },
                ...
            },
            {
                "id":{
                    "deck":2,
                    "card":{
                        "id":3,
                        "name":"Card 3"
                    }
                },
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Deck 3",
        "cards":[
            {
                "id":{
                    "deck":3,
                    "card":3 // I expected this to be the full model of Card 3
                },
                ...
            },
            {
                "id":{
                    "deck":3,
                    "card":{
                        "id":4,
                        "name":"Card 4"
                    }
                },
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I'd guess that this has something to do with a default setting to avoid unnecessary repetition, but I haven't found anything in the JPA documentation to suggest why this is happening or how to prevent it.

**Edit:**

I've tried changing `Deck.cards`, `DeckCardId.deck`, and `DeckCardId.card` to eager, and I get the same result. I did notice in debugging, however, that even with `FetchType.LAZY` I get the full `DeckCard.id.card` object in Eclipse, and it's only after the `List<Deck>` has been serialized that the JSON only contains the id for subsequent appearances of each card. Could it be a Jackson serialization issue, rather than a JPA issue?

## Code

Deck.java

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id",
    scope = Deck.class
)
public class Deck {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "id.deck",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    private List<DeckCard> cards;

    // standard getters & setters
}
```

DeckCard.java

```
@Entity
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "id.deck", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "deck_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "id.card", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "card_id"))
})
public class DeckCard implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private DeckCardId id = new DeckCardId();

    private int quantity;

    public DeckCard() {}

    // standard getters & setters for id & quantity

    @Transient
    public Deck getDeck() {
        return getId().getDeck();
    }

    public void setDeck(Deck deck) {
        getId().setDeck(deck);
    }

    @Transient
    public Card getCard() {
        return getId().getCard();
    }

    public void setCard(Card card) {
        getId().setCard(card);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        DeckCard that = (DeckCard) o;
        if (getId() != null ? !getId().equals(that.getId()) : that.getId() != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

DeckCardId.java

```
@Embeddable
public class DeckCardId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6470278480687272622L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private Deck deck;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private Card card;

    // standard getters & setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        DeckCardId that = (DeckCardId) o;
        if (deck != null ? !deck.equals(that.deck) : that.deck != null)
            return false;
        if (card != null ? !card.equals(that.card) : that.card != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (deck != null ? deck.hashCode() : 0);
        return 31 * result + (card != null ? card.hashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

## Solution

While I hadn't originally posted the code for the `Card` class, the selected answer made me realize that it contained the same `JsonIdentityInfo` annotation that `Deck` did:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id",
    scope = Card.class
)
public class Card {

    // rest of class
```

By removing this annotation from `Card`, all instances after the first of each `Card` are serialized in full instead of by reference.

Comment: It is defined as lazy. The details wouldn't be loaded unless you call the get method. Try changing to eager and see the behavior.

Comment: @notionquest Thanks for the suggestion! I'll edit the question, but the short answer is that it produced the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem the other day. Turns out that it's not JPA's fault (you can see in the debugger that it correctly maps all instances) but rather the Jackson serializer.

You need to modify or remove the `JsonIdentityInfo` from your class and suddenly all instances will have their relationships mapped!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I didn't put the code for `Card` in (I'll edit the question), but it also had the `JsonIdentityInfo` which was causing all instances after the first to be serialized by reference instead of in full.